# Host doesn't support nested folder structures for deployment. How do I adjust Composer?

Tags: 8, composer, deployment

So, I have to deploy a drupal 8 site to a host which doesn't provide functionality to specify an entry point for a Drupal site which is nested below the site root folder. How can I update the folder structure to have everything in the server's site root?
What I tried initially was to move the contents of the `site_root/web/` folder up to the site root, but this causes 500 errors. I'm not sure since I can't see the errors on the host server, but replicating the scenario on my dev machine points to the autoloader.php file looking in the wrong place `PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/ab-test/../vendor/autoload.php'`.

I have tried to resolve this by first following the suggestion to re-run `composer install` from the site root but that doesn't seem to help. When I manually update where the autoloader.php should be looking, I then get this error`PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/ab-test/vendor/composer/../../load.environment.php)` which again suggests that the file/folder structure is being set somewhere I'm not thinking of or don't have enough experience to check. 
So, my convoluted question comes down to how do I switch from a nested to a non-nested folder structure without everything freaking out?

Comment: Apache or nginx?

Comment: It's an apache server, shared of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using an Apache server, you may try to set the Drupal root folder using an `.htaccess` file in your site_root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

(Replace `example.com` with your actual domain name.)

This way, you can keep the "nested" folder structure created using Composer and serve all requests for your domain with the `web` sub folder.

Comment: I'd read this, but didn't have the admin chops to implement. Does this come with a performance hit?

Comment: The rewrite itself shouldn't matter as much in terms of performance, as using `.htaccess` does instead of a proper vhost configuration. But obviously it's your only choice on your shared hosting. If you experience performance bottlenecks, it's unlikely to be caused by this little rewrite.

Comment: @nizz0k Careful with this one, you might be open to a kind of directory traversal attack. If you can't change the root path for the vhost, apache will (or at least did last time I checked a few years ago) still serve anything you can physically get to in the parent of ./web. For example: http://example.com/web/../private_files/my_password.txt. Since "web/" is at the start of the request URI, the rewrite rule won't kick in, and if the file exists apache will probably serve it

Comment: Thanks Clive, I'm looking into alternatives. It's a European host and I have some language issues trying to get support. I hope to get a more robust solution implemented soon.